# Is there a Seifert–van Kampen theorem for etale fondemental group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Is there a Seifert–van Kampen theorem for etale fondemental group? (for example for varieties over a non-algebraically closed field) Any example is welcome.

Comment: Is this SGA1 IX.5.1 (in this case where S' is the disjoint union of two open sets covering S)?

Comment: It is even easier than SvK for the topological fundamental group, as it simply amounts to etale descent for finite etale covers.

Comment: See [J. Stix, *A general Seifert-Van Kampen theorem for algebraic fundamental groups*, Publications of RIMS 42 (2006), no. 3, 763-786]

Comment: @Z.Zhou If possible, once you get some idea can you write down some rough sketch here...